# Splitting on white space

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a scenario like i need to check a string if it has only one word. I split on white space and its fine, now I need to check if a single word has a space attached to it and I'm unable to handle it.

I tried the below and Its not working

```
    String temp1[] = temp.split("\\s+");

System.out.println("Size   "+temp1.length);

if(temp1.length==1 && !temp1[0].contains(" "));
{
    System.out.println("Single keyword");
}
```

I need to avoid the single word along with a space.

Comment: I tried with a string "test " and it worked all fine. What's the problem you're facing?

Comment: @R.J: Oops, missed that part, thought he was getting string length. It's always confusing when an OP posts something like `not working`.

Comment: @R.J Acutually if a word is "test " then it should not be a single keyword.

Comment: you can try it with regex expressions

Comment: what should it be? How should it be handled? You've need to give a sample I/O for the case which you need help for, as people here won't have much of an idea about it.

Answer (score 3):

first remove starting & ending white spaces using `trim()` method & then split it

Ex:~

if your i/p is String s= "Hello   " then 
 s.trim() gives "Hello".

read documentation once you will get an idea.

Comment: Yeah, I missed this , TnQ

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if a string has one and only word or not.So basically if a string has atleast one space then that string is not considered as single word(simple grammar).So you need to check if that particular string has any spaces or not.

```
String t1="hhh fff";
        if(t1.contains(" "))
        {
            System.out.println("yes");
        }
```

above will also check if a string is prefixed or post fixed with space